# Underscan with AMD HD7560D proprietary driver on Philips TV

Tags: ubuntu, hdmi

I've just started setting up and HTPC and installed Zorin OS. I've got some problems when plugging it into my tv via hdmi.

If I use the open source drivers I get no audio via hdmi. So I did some research and most people suggested using the proprietary drivers. I went this route and get audio, however, I now get what I have learned is called underscan. The image displayed on the screen is not filling the screen. There is about an inch missing on either side of the display.

If I lower the display resolution (below 1080p) then the screen fills up.

Most solutions have suggested I go into CCC and play with the scan slider, however, I don't have this slider in my CCC dialog. Is there some way change these settings via the shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found an answer in the [Ubuntu how tos](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI#HDTV_underscan).

Just have to set the underscale to 0 via a shell command.

`sudo aticonfig --set-pcs-val=MCIL,DigitalHDTVDefaultUnderscan,0`

Then reboot.